# Multi-function partial derivatives confusion.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: question 7]
This question is giving me a hard time conceptually.  I know with respect to u the derivative should be Fx Xu + Fy Yu and then substitute v instead of u for respect with v.  Out of the information given, I'm having trouble finding the Xu, Yu, Xv, Yv.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the multi-variable chain rule:

$$z_u=f_xx_u+f_yy_u$$

It's easy to see that

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac\partial{\partial u}u^2+v^2=2u$$

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac\partial{\partial u}\frac uv=\frac1v$$

Plugging in known values, we have

$$f_u(-18,-6)=f_xx_u+f_yy_u=-14\cdot2\cdot18+\frac16=-\frac{3023}6$$

Can you find $f_v(-18,-6)$ like this?

Comment: by Fx (360, 3)=-11 and Fy(360,3) = 18, the shouldn't Zu = (-11)(-36)+(18)(-1/6)=393? I still don't understand how you chose the plug in values.

Comment: @Megannn I calculated $x_u$ and $y_u$.  $f_x$ and $f_y$ are already given, and they are not the coordinate points.

Comment: Xu = 2u, so should it not be 14(-36)+(1/6) ?? I'm sorry I still can't see where the -14 and 18 is from.

Comment: the answer was 393

Comment: @Megannn Yes, $x_y=2u$, that was my mistake.  And that's odd, I'm not sure it should be 393... Hm...